# Extract string from the second single quotes using R

Tags: r

I need to extract the string from the second single quotes using R like in the below example
Success: 'Standard Work Violation' for 'ahshi' on 2018-12-01 Days (P-9-A965K735).

The problem is that the string length constantly changes for different instances and I cannot use the logic of extracting string between the position 11 and 33.
The only logic should be to extract the string from the second single quotes
irrespective of where the quotes are.

Is there any way to go about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` with regular expressions:

```
mystring <- "'Standard Work Violation' for 'ahshi' on 2018-12-01 Days (P-9-A965K735)."

sub(".*'[^']*'.*'(.+?)'.*", "\\1", mystring)
# [1] "ahshi"
```